# Celery: Object of type AsyncResult is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, celery

I am running my function with help of celery and celery beat

I have this error: (returned object isn't in json format)

```
celery_1_a510f09c95a3 | [2022-08-30 01:30:00,069: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task 
parser_app.views.periodic_exctract_urls[d65eb6a3-187b-4f48-afe6-b7df101cdbcd] raised 
unexpected: EncodeError(TypeError('Object of type AsyncResult is not JSON serializable'))
```

**My code** (the first function returns a list of ints)

```
@shared_task()
def periodic_exctract_urls():
    print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} Start periodic_exctract_urls")
    celery_results = []
    film_name_queries = SearchQuery.objects.filter(is_site_search=False)
    url_queries = SearchQuery.objects.filter(is_site_search=True)
    for film in film_name_queries:
        celery_results.append(make_requests.delay(str(film.name)))
    
    for url in url_queries:
        for film in film_name_queries:
            celery_results.append(make_requests.delay(
                f"site:{url.name} {film.name}"
            ))

    task_ids = []
    task_ids.extend([result.collect() for result in celery_results])
    return task_ids
    
    @shared_task()
    def make_requests(search_text) -> int:
        ...
        return int(created_task.pk)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `make_requests.delay`, you got `AsyncResult`([doc](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult)). If you would like to get the return value from `make_request` task, you can use `collect` method. For example:

```py
@shared_task()
def periodic_exctract_urls():
    print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} Start periodic_exctract_urls")
    task_ids = []
    film_name_queries = SearchQuery.objects.filter(is_site_search=False)
    url_queries = SearchQuery.objects.filter(is_site_search=True)
    results = []
    for film in film_name_queries:
        results.append(make_requests.delay(str(film.name)))
    ...
    task_ids.extend([result.collect() for result in results])
    return task_ids


@shared_task()
def make_requests(search_text) -> int:
    ...
    return int(created_task.pk)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have ```AsyncResult is not JSON serializable```

Updated code of periodic_exctract_urls in the question

Comment: Where did the exception raise? Please give the `lineno`.

Comment: return task_ids

Comment: log the `task_ids`, confirm all elements of this `list` is `JSON serializable`